# Отключение консоли в visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как в `MSVC++` сделать так, чтобы консоль не появлялась?

Comment: Поясните свой вопрос. Вы хотите чтобы у консольной программы не появлялась консоль? Или вам нужен способ запуска программы, так чтобы у неё не было видимых окон? или что-то ещё?

Comment: что бы у консольной программы "не появлялась консоль" она должна быть "неконсольной".

Comment: вот ответ, кому будет интересно
http://esate.ru/uroki/OpenGL/uroki_opengl/_p4200/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете приложение как приложение windows, а не как консольное. При этом вы сможете выводить в файл,  т.д. и т.п. - просто, грубо говоря, в фоне. Окна создаваться тоже не будут.

Т.е. у вас не будет ввода от пользователя (опять же, читать из файла можно), не будет вывода на экран.

Если это устраивает - то вперед. В командной строке, например, эти флаг линковщика `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`.